# Disable Constraints Temporarily

Tags: mysql, database

I have many tables with relationship constraints. Tables contain full of dummy data, i would like to truncate/empty the data from the tables while keeping the structure.

Everytime i want to empty a table, i get foreign key constraint errors. What can i do to disable the constraint temporarily and then set enable it back once dummy data are deleted.

I tried this solution, but didn't work! Once i disable, then try to truncate, i get fk constraint error...

```
//disable
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;


//enable
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I'm using MySQL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remove the FK if you want to use `truncate`, as truncate not a logged operation.

Can use `delete` with FK in place but delete is a logged operation and takes longer.

Answer (score 3):

Start at the end (tables that are only FK) and not referenced BY any other tales.  Those you can truncate.  Then work your way up and delete.  If you truncate / delete in the proper order then you will not violate the contraints.   Or you could drop all the constaints.  Truncate the tables.   Then add the contraints back in.